# how to install akonadi 5.2 on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: kmail, akonadi

I am trying to set up KMail on Ubuntu 16.04 (not Kubuntu) and I am affected by [this bug](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=354056). The bug seems to have been resolved, but at the very end of the topic in the bugtracker one can read that the version containing the fix is akonadi 5.2, while the version installed via repo (as reported by `akonadictl --version`) is 5.1.51.

How can I install a newer version of akonadi containing the fix?

Answer (score -1):

Normally to install a newer version in an older environment we would use backporting.  It looks like backporting of a newer version of akonadi is not available for Ubuntu 16.04.  Reference this post:

[Backport of kdepim / kmail](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2341803)

I recommend upgrading to Ubuntu 17.04 and installing PIM 16.12.3

[KDEPIM Update](https://kubuntu.org/news/kde-pim-update-now-available-for-zesty-zapus-17-04/)

I did that on Kubuntu and Kmail is running a lot better.  You'll end up with Akonadai 5.4.3 and Kmail 5.4.3